# How to get notifications when app was closed/minimized using Codename one for Android and ios

Tags: codenameone

I have developed my app to get notifications while it was minimized , but our Requirement is to get notifications even app was closed , how can i implement this using codename one,anyone please help me

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification and background notifications both work when the app is closed and should show an entry in the pulldown menu as long as the push type isn't 2 or something like that.

Comment: I checked for background notifications when i closed my app as you said but the notifications doesn't shown in the pulldown menu/notification Bar.So is there any possibility to run background service when app was closed to get notifications@Shai Almog

Comment: How did you post the notification? Notice that notifications on iOS will only appear if the app is in the background.

Comment: I did it with help of performBackgroundFetch() method local notifications are getting when app was minimized. So guide me to write Service to get notifications when app was closed .@Shai Almog

Comment: If you schedule them they will appear even if your app is there. I think what you are describing is push notification

Comment: no,am describing local notificatins, and also i scheduled them but i didnt get any notifications when app was closed . So tell me is there any possibility to write service to get notifications when app was closed without using Push Notifications @shai Almog

Comment: Notifications work for me when the app is closed, make sure you passed the right time argument and other values